# Handling Errors Axios Catch when data isnt present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I set up axios like this

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response;
}, error => {
 if (error.response.status === 400) {
   
  return <Redirect to="/badrequest"></Redirect>;

 }
 return error;
});
```

when I hit 400 it doesnt redirect and since the data on the page that was expected wasn't fetched I get an error saying the data is null. Instead I want to redirect to a page and forget about the past request

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the error.?

Comment: You can't use the `<Redirect>` component like this. You have to [create a separate history object](https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l#4-createhistory) which you share between this code and the `<Router>`

Comment: @Martin what if i want to return a component?

Comment: @lamboktulus1379 yes it works properly

Comment: @Martin You arent answering the question that im asking. I know that and thats why I asked. How do i return a component when 400 happens. Also for the record you get an error when you return a component so you arent "free" to return a unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return JSX like this and expect it to effect anything. A `Redirect` component would need to be rendered into the DOM. If you want to imperatively navigate then you should access a "global" history object and issue an imperative redirect to the new route.

```
// import global history object

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response;
}, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 400) {
    return history.replace("/badrequest");
  }
  return error;
});
```

Comment: what if i want to return a component?

Comment: @ariannnn React doesn't work this way, returning a component/JSX likely won't do anything for you since axios and the interceptor are operating outside React lifecycle. It would be more correct to return a "flag" in the error response and then handle the request error ***in*** the React component and issue the imperative redirect, or set some local state and conditionally render a `Redirect` component ***into*** the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from the discussion that you are quite adamant about using the `<Redirect>` component, I think you have to ditch the interceptor approach.
In your component that is invoking the axios fetch you will need to do the `status === 400` check, and render the `<Redirect>` into the DOM if this is the case.
About re-usability: your best bet is probably to move the fetch-and-check into a custom hook and re-use the custom hook.

```
const { data, badrequest } = useCheckedData(someUrl);

return (
  <div>
    { badrequest && <Redirect to={'/badrequest'} /> }
    {
      data && (
        // render data
      )
    }
  </div>
);
```

```
export const useCheckedData = (url) => {
  // useState for data and badrequest,
  // useEffect, and axios stuff goes here

  // and something like this
  axios.get(url).then( ... ).catch(
    (error) => { if (error.response.status === 400) setBadrequest(true) }
  )

  return { data, badrequest };
}
```